# Are all end() iterators equivalent for a collection type?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, language-lawyer

Given a particular stl collection in C++, is the `end()` value equivalent for all instances of  the same templatization?  In other words, will the following work for all stl containers and circumstances (not just for std::map)?

```
std::map<Key, Value> foo(int seed);

std::map<Key, Value> instance1 = foo(1);
std::map<Key, Value> instance2 = foo(2);
std::map<Key, Value>::iterator itr = instance1.begin();
std::map<Key, Value>::iterator endItr = instance2.end(); // Comes from other collection!

for (; itr != endItr; ++itr) {
  // Do something on each key value pair...
}
```

Comment: Might work in a particular implementation, but you can only count in it for types that create an "end" iterator with the default ctor (e.g., `std::istream_iterator`). Even inn these cases, nothing guarantees it directly.

Comment: If this works, consider yourself unlucky.  That's clearly a bug in your code.  I thought MSVC would detect this type of iterator misuse but perhaps that's only checked iterators.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: I thought this is guaranteed to work on MSVC because they implement [SCARY iterators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx).

Comment: @Jesse:  Not quite. SCARY iterators allow you to mix iterator types regardless of the comparator/allocator types, so that `std::map<K,V>::iterator` is the same type as `std::map<K,V, custom_compare>::iterator`, but it doesn't mean that the end iterators from the two maps have identical values.

Comment: @DaveS: Ah, right, SCARY iterators is only talking about type equivalence and not value equivalence. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because of the STL container and iterator requirements:

**23.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]**

> 6 begin() returns an iterator referring to the ﬁrst element in the
>   container. end() returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value
>   for the container. If the container is empty, then begin() == end();

**24.2.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]**

> 6 An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if
>   there is a ﬁnite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that
>   makes i == j. If j is reachable from i, they refer to elements of the
>   same sequence.

The equality of `begin()` and `end()` for empty containers means that `begin()` and `end()` need to be part of the same container objects, and hence `end()` cannot be a static member of a container class. Note also that -except for forward iterators- applying `operator--` on `end()` would be impossible to resolve with a static `end()` iterator.

Comment: How do you know that doesn't work? What if `std::map::end` returns an object which is the same for all maps of a certain specialization?

Comment: @mfontanini: Can we not just consider undefined behavior synonymous with "not working"?  Do we have to spell it out every time?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley well, it's a legitimate question and in the end the Standard spells it out

Comment: @K-ballo why not? example please

Comment: @rhalbersma: Remember how C++ allows you to overload operators?

Comment: My point was that it's undefined behavior to compare iterators from 2 different containers.  So even if it appears to work on some implementation, we should still be able to say "it doesn't work" without being taken to task for it simply because it technically does work on those implementations. (if I'm mistaken about mfontanini's implication, my apologies)

Comment: By the way, I think the biggest barrier for your static `end()` idea is `operator--`.  Where should it go if it doesn't know what container object it belongs to?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley good point but that does not apply to `forward_list`, or any other user-made node-based container with only forward iterators.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley no, my question was referred to why OP was saying that wouldn't work. Does the standard say so? Is there any requirement for `end()`? That deserved a quote from the standard(it does now). Just saying "that won't work" does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, that is not portable. It may work by coincidence on some platform.

There are end-iterators that *can* be re-used for different ranges, such as the default-constructed istream_iterator:

```
ifstream a("foo.txt");
ifstream b("bar.txt");
istream_iterator<string> end;
istream_iterator<string> ia( a);
istream_iterator<string> ib( b);
// from here on both [ia, end> and [ib, end> are valid ranges.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it yourself:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
map<int,int> m1;
map<int,int> m2;

int main() {
  cout<<(m1.end() == m2.end())<<endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/o18DtQ

> output:
>
> ```
> 0
> ```